# How do I match subscript with a regular expression in VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba

Among other strings, I am trying to match the string `LC₅₀`
In VBA I am able to type superscript characters but not subscript characters.
I have the following regular expression

```
Dim r1 As Object
Set r1 = New RegExp
r1.Pattern = "^(\(?[a-z].*[a-z]\)?\.?,?-?:?|\(?\d{1,5}|%,?|[a-z]|LC50|\D.*³|[A-Z]\d{1},?|\(?\d{1,4}\..*\)?|°.*|[A-Z]\d(-|:).*|MPa|\(o-,|m-,|p-\))$": r1.Global = True: Set r1Matches = r1.Execute(Replace(arry(i), "- ", "-"))
```

My question is:
How do I match the following standalone string with a regular expression in VBA
`LC₅₀`

Comment: Just replace `LC50` with `LC[5₅][0₀]`. See https://regex101.com/r/sylFX0/2

Comment: The problem is that when I paste the subscript characters in VBA they become normal (not subscript) characters). I don't know how to add subscript characters in VBA

Comment: What about `LC[5\u2085][0\u2080]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `LC50` with `LC[5\u2085][0\u2080]`.

With some other small enhancements, the pattern can look like

```
^(\(?[a-z].*[a-z]\)?\.?,?-?:?|\(?\d{1,5}|%,?|[a-z]|LC[5\u2085][0\u2080]|\D.*³|[A-Z]\d,?|\(?\d{1,4}\..*\)?|°.*|[A-Z]\d[-:].*|MPa|\([om]-,|p-\))$
```

Here,

- `\(o-,|\(m-,` is replaced with `\([om]-,`
- `[A-Z]\d(-|:).*` replaced with `[A-Z]\d[-:].*`
- The `{1}` is removed, as it is always redundant.

The subscript number codes are

| Number | Code |
| --- | --- |
| `\u2080` | ₀ |
| `\u2081` | ₁ |
| `\u2082` | ₂ |
| `\u2083` | ₃ |
| `\u2084` | ₄ |
| `\u2085` | ₅ |
| `\u2086` | ₆ |
| `\u2087` | ₇ |
| `\u2088` | ₈ |
| `\u2089` | ₉ |